# adding new column to pandas multi-index dataframe using rolling().max()

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have the following dataframe with multi-index:

```
dates = pd.date_range(start='2016-01-01 09:30:00', periods=20, freq='s')
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1] * 20 + [2] * 12 + [3] * 8,
               'B': np.concatenate((dates, dates)),
             'C': np.arange(40)})
df = df.set_index(["B","A"])
```

Now I want to create a new columns being the maximum value of the last two values for index A. I tried the following:

```
df.loc[:,"D"] = df.groupby(level="A").rolling(2).max()
```

But it only produces N/A for the new column ("D), since the order of the grouped dataframe index is the opposite of the original dataframe.

How can I solve this? I prefer to stay away from stacking/unstacking, swaplevel/sortlevel, join or concat since I have a big dataframe and these operations tend to be quite time consuming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop` parameter for remove first level of MultiIndex:

```
df['D'] = df.groupby(level="A")['C'].rolling(2).max().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
print (df)
                        C     D
B                   A          
2016-01-01 09:30:00 1   0   NaN
2016-01-01 09:30:01 1   1   1.0
2016-01-01 09:30:02 1   2   2.0
2016-01-01 09:30:03 1   3   3.0
2016-01-01 09:30:04 1   4   4.0
2016-01-01 09:30:05 1   5   5.0
2016-01-01 09:30:06 1   6   6.0
2016-01-01 09:30:07 1   7   7.0
2016-01-01 09:30:08 1   8   8.0
2016-01-01 09:30:09 1   9   9.0
2016-01-01 09:30:10 1  10  10.0
2016-01-01 09:30:11 1  11  11.0
2016-01-01 09:30:12 1  12  12.0
2016-01-01 09:30:13 1  13  13.0
2016-01-01 09:30:14 1  14  14.0
2016-01-01 09:30:15 1  15  15.0
2016-01-01 09:30:16 1  16  16.0
2016-01-01 09:30:17 1  17  17.0
2016-01-01 09:30:18 1  18  18.0
2016-01-01 09:30:19 1  19  19.0
2016-01-01 09:30:00 2  20   NaN
2016-01-01 09:30:01 2  21  21.0
...
...
```

because:

```
print (df.groupby(level="A")['C'].rolling(2).max())
A  B                    A
1  2016-01-01 09:30:00  1     NaN
   2016-01-01 09:30:01  1     1.0
   2016-01-01 09:30:02  1     2.0
   2016-01-01 09:30:03  1     3.0
   2016-01-01 09:30:04  1     4.0
   2016-01-01 09:30:05  1     5.0
   2016-01-01 09:30:06  1     6.0
   2016-01-01 09:30:07  1     7.0
   2016-01-01 09:30:08  1     8.0
   2016-01-01 09:30:09  1     9.0
   2016-01-01 09:30:10  1    10.0
   2016-01-01 09:30:11  1    11.0
   2016-01-01 09:30:12  1    12.0
   2016-01-01 09:30:13  1    13.0
   2016-01-01 09:30:14  1    14.0
   2016-01-01 09:30:15  1    15.0
   2016-01-01 09:30:16  1    16.0
   2016-01-01 09:30:17  1    17.0
   2016-01-01 09:30:18  1    18.0
   2016-01-01 09:30:19  1    19.0
2  2016-01-01 09:30:00  2     NaN
   2016-01-01 09:30:01  2    21.0
...
...
```